# PHP PDO inserting bulk records or update if exists

Tags: sql, pdo, bulkinsert, insert-update

I have this code that insert mulitple rows in one query which works.

What I would like it to do no is if colA already exists in the database update colB.

I've looked at using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but I can only see it working for one row at a time where I could have 1000 rows.

How can i use the INSERT/UPDATE on my code?

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (colA, colB, colC, colD, colE) VALUES';
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
$n = 0;
// and loop through the array binding values from each row
// to the placeholders before execution
// placeholders names increment starting at 0 to array length
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $insertQuery[] = '(
        :colA' . $n . ',
        :colB' . $n . ',
        :colC' . $n . ',
        :colD' . $n . ',
        :colE' . $n . '
    )';

    $insertData['colA' . $n] = $row['colA'];
    $insertData['colB' . $n] = $row['colB'];
    $insertData['colC' . $n] = $row['colC'];
    $insertData['colD' . $n] = $row['colD'];
    $insertData['colE' . $n] = $row['load_note'];
    $insertData['last_updated' . $n] = $row['colE'];
    $n++;
}

// prepare the query and exeute it
if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
    $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

EDIT:

How do I update multiple columns?  Is this correct?

```
$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = VALUES(colB, colC)";
```

EDIT2:

I added this but i get no rows inserting (empty table)

```
$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE colA = VALUES(colA), 
                  colB = VALUES(colB), 
                  colC = VALUES(colC), 
                  colD = VALUES(colD), 
                  colE = VALUES(colE))";
```

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should work properly for multiple rows, since you can use `VALUES(columnName)` to get the value of the column from that attempted insert.

Comment: -1 for the documentation that makes no sense

Comment: @Your Common Sense.  A suggestion on how to get this to work instead of a downvote just because I didn't understand the documentation would be more appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the `implode()` call, add:

```
$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE colB = VALUES(colB)";
```

Assuming `colA` has a unique key, then whenever that column already exists, this will set `colB` to the new `colB` from that row of the `INSERT`, and leave all the other columns unchanged.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

It has the following example that shows that each duplicate row is handled independently.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

That statement is identical to the following two statements:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=3;
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=9;
```

Comment: Will that for each row that needs to be updated, update that rows new value.  Some rows with colB may be the same others need updating with different values

Comment: Yeah i did but it made no sense

Comment: Just checking to make sure it works as I think other part of my query are getting all the fields i need.  Once it works, I'll accept